# Redmine error log fatal:not a git repository

Tags: gitlab, redmine

I installed redmine on git server (gitlab), which is our main git server (same machine).

When I add the repository (through gitlab) information in redmine web,

The redmine log says:

> /usr/local/redmine/log/production.scm.stderr.log <
>   fatal: Not a git repository: '/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories/woojs/RedmineTestProject.git/'

But when I check the whether bare or non-bare using git command, I get this:

```
root@gitserver:/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories/woojs/RedmineTestProject.git# git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
true
```

I tried to change some things related to permissions: Changing owner to www-data and changing permissions to 777. It's still not working.

Comment: FrankerZ so what did you do to make it work in the end ?
How did @VonC 's answer help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar [to this old thread](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/19606), check the account which runs for redmine: does that account has the right to access `/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories/woojs/RedmineTestProject.git`? (or anything under `/data/gitlab/git-data/repositories/`?)

This usually is a right access issue.