# Redmine and Git - stderr: fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab, redmine

I am integrating Redmine with Gitlab repositories. When I try to access Repository tab in Redmine, I get error in Apache logs:

```
stderr: fatal: Not a git repository: '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/example-group/example-repository.git'
```

I know that it is access/permissions problem.

The same problem described in SO thread: [Redmine error log fatal:not a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265066/redmine-error-log-fatalnot-a-git-repository). I have tried adding nobody, apache or www-data users to git group but it didn't solve the problem.

When I make `sudo chmod 755` full path to the repository `gitlab/git-data/repositories/example-group/example-repository.git`, it works well.

How to solve this problem without changing permissions to 755?

Answer (score 2):

- Check under which user account Redmine runs
- Check whether the `git` group actually has access to that directory
- Add the Redmine user to the `git` group or whichever group has access to the repository